# Print and log stdout and stderr in fish shell

Tags: stdout, stderr, tee, fish

I am using the `fish` shell and try to log stdout and stderr into two separate files and printing them in the terminal at the same time (e.g., by piping each stream to `tee`).

In `bash` I would do (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/692407/5082444):

```bsh
command > >(tee -a stdout.log) 2> >(tee -a stderr.log >&2)
```

How can I achieve the same in the `fish` shell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something similar with

```
begin; command | tee -a stdout.log ; end ^| tee -a stderr.log >&2
```

with the proviso that if the first `tee` writes anything to stderr, it will also get logged, which is not the case with the bash version.

Comment: Does this permit interaction? I have a process that prints prompts and expects a response.

Comment: You may have problems, because output from the process might get buffered and you wont see the prompt until after you have typed the response. For example, create a file `abc` then use as command `rm -i abc` and you will not see the message `rm: remove regular empty file 'abc'? ` until too late.